# Changed meta viewport content on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the viewport content on click so that users can then pinch zoom on images when they're loaded into the modal and then when the modal closes change the viewport content back to normal.

```
//button to open the modal and change the viewport content 
$('#product-zoom').on('touchstart', function () {
                    console.log('found html')
                    $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
                    $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=12, user-scalable=yes">');
            });
//button to close the modal and change the viewport
            $('.btnZoomerClose').on('click', function () {
                console.log('close modal')
                $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">');
            });
```

for some reason the close doesn't change the viewport back to normal.

any suggestions or info would be great!

Comment: What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the viewport back to normal, but you setting the same attribute for the viewports when you open and close the modal..Do you mean you want to return

```
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">');
```

back to

```
$('meta[name=viewport]')
```